# Ninja forms - After submission redirect using submission id

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I'm using Ninja forms 3.2.11.

I created a form at this url www.mysite.it.

How can I redirect user to www.mysite.it?submission={submission_id} after submit where {submission_id} is the form submission id I've just submitted?

I tried using 'ninja_forms_after_submission' hook as doc said in this way:

```
add_action( 'ninja_forms_after_submission', 'my_ninja_forms_after_submission' );
function my_ninja_forms_after_submission( $form_data ){
        $id = $form_data['actions']['save']['sub_id'];
        wp_redirect( "www.mysite.it?submission" . $id );
        exit;

}
```

In this way ninja forms ajax submission function failed with 302 Not found and redirect not happens.

Anyone knows what it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an equals after submission:

```
Incorrect:
    wp_redirect( "www.mysite.it?submission" . $id );
Correct:
    wp_redirect( "www.mysite.it?submission=" . $id );
```